# Asana API - how add attachment to task via attachment_gid, not file/stream upload?

Tags: attachment, asana-api

I uploaded the file to asana and I have its gid. The file is quite large and I don't want to spend traffic and server resources for the script to work so that this file is added to all the tasks I need.
I tried to make updates and history through tasks, but there are no visible changes. The API documentation does not provide for such a method either, but perhaps someone will advise a working solution.